# Entity Framework Error: error loading specified metadata resource

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, import, metadata

I know this is a known issue, but the solution for my case isn't in other question, I think.

I have a project in C#. In this project I have my edmx. For some reasons, not relevant here, I have to move the edmx in other C# project. So, I have create a new project and create a new edmx, as the other edmx.

But now, I don't know why it says me "unable to load the specified metadata resource" when I try to access to the data, for example in this simple code:

```
foreach (TabTerminali p in (from r in dbContext.TabTerminali select r).ToList())
    Debug.WriteLine(p.ABILITATO);
```

I'm sure the connection string is right, because it's the same as the other working edmx.

The Metadata Artifact Processing is:

```
<Connection>
  <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
  </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
</Connection>
```

The compiler does its work without errors.

Where is the error/problem? It seems to be the exact copy of the other my edmx model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the working solution for me [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1580276.aspx?Entity%20Framework%20Entity%20Model%20in%20a%20separated%20dll)